# sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to change the following parameter in a *local.conf* file

```
....
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc31"
.....
```

I need to change `db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc31"` to  `db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xyz123"`

I used the command

```
sed -i 'db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/${DB_NAME}"' /root/local.conf
```

where ${DB_NAME} is an env variable and it updates the `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<current db name>"` (which in this case is `abc31`). But the command throws me the error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you used sed before? (I ask because your command doesn't really look like a sed command, and I'm not clear on why you expect it to do what you describe.) You might want to read through the sed manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Comment: No, I haven't, this is my first time using sed. any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, a sed command consists of an optional *address* (which indicate(s) the lines that you want to touch, either by specifying line numbers or by specifying a regex), followed by a *command*, followed by whatever arguments or options that command takes.

Your command passes this script to sed:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/${DB_NAME}"
```

so there's no address; the command is 'd' (meaning "delete and move on"); and the rest of the script, `b.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/${DB_NAME}"`, doesn't actually make sense to sed, because the 'd' command doesn't take any arguments or options.

Instead, I think you want this script:

```
s#^db.default.url=.*#db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xyz123"#
```

which uses the 's' command to replace anything matching the regex `^db.default.url=.*` with the string `db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xyz123"`. (Note: usually we use `/` to set off the regex and replacement, but in this case I've used `#` to avoid having to escape every occurrence of `/` inside the replacement string.)

So your full Bash command, which runs that sed script, would look like this:

```bash
sed -i \
  's#^db.default.url=.*#db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/'"$DB_NAME"'"#' \
  /root/local.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, setting field separator and output field separator as `/` for all lines. Then checking if line starts from `db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:[0-9]+/` then set last field to your new value and print edited/non-edited lines.

Also creating an `awk` variable named `dbName` which is having your shell variable value in it.

```
awk -v dbName="$DB_NAME" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="/"
}
/^db\.default\.url="jdbc:mysql:\/\/localhost:[0-9]+\//{
  $NF=dbName
}
1
' Input_file
```

Above will only print the value on terminal, check its output once you are Happy with shown output of above code then use following code to save output into Input_file itself:

```
awk -v dbName="$DB_NAME" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="/"
}
/^db\.default\.url="jdbc:mysql:\/\/localhost:[0-9]+\//{
  $NF=dbName
}
1
' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

Comment: The last variable is an env variable which is ${DB_NAME}

Comment: @merilstack, that's ok, I have edited my code, please do check it once and let me know, refresh this page once and use latest code, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Here the Input_file is the local.conf file?

Comment: @merilstack, yes please.